# Merge two multidimensional arrays into a new multi-array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two multidimensional arrays that I need to merge into a new multi-array. I've seen some other similar questions here but have not found one that fulfill my needs.

Example:

```
var array1 = [[ 4.242, 'ORTIa', 5.16 ],
  [ 4.016, 'RAIL', 25.9 ],
  [ 4.013, 'BILIa', 93.3 ]]

var array2 = [[ -2.9491, 'MSABb', 36.2 ],
  [ -2.9046, 'EMPIRb', 11.7 ],
  [ -2.8286, 'EDGE', 5.84 ]]
```

I need the output to look like:

```
[[ 4.242, 'ORTIa', 5.16, -2.9491, 'MSABb', 36.2 ],
  [ 4.016, 'RAIL', 25.9, -2.9046, 'EMPIRb', 11.7 ],
  [ 4.013, 'BILIa', 93.3, -2.8286, 'EDGE', 5.84 ]]
```

Any idea how to solve this? 
Thank you!

Comment: Iterate over both 2D arrays. Append entry of second to entry of first. Store result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `map` on one of the arrays and in the callback expect an index as well, then just concatenate each list with the list on the same `index` in the other array.

The code should look like the following:

```
let array3 = array1.map((list, index) => list.concat(array2[index]));
console.log(array3);

//array3 will have the expected result as mentioned in your question.
```

Comment: *"The `concat()` method is used to merge two or more arrays. **This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.**"* - [MDN `Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) For this to work you need to assign the result back to `array1`. eg `array1 = array1.map(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Naive solution:

```
var array1 = [[ 4.242, 'ORTIa', 5.16 ],
  [ 4.016, 'RAIL', 25.9 ],
  [ 4.013, 'BILIa', 93.3 ]];

var array2 = [[ -2.9491, 'MSABb', 36.2 ],
  [ -2.9046, 'EMPIRb', 11.7 ],
  [ -2.8286, 'EDGE', 5.84 ]];

var array3 = [];

for( var  i = 0; i < array1.length; i++ )
{
  array3[ i ] = array1[ i ].concat( array2[ i ] );
}

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Map` makes it easy for you.

```js
var array1 = [[ 4.242, 'ORTIa', 5.16 ],
  [ 4.016, 'RAIL', 25.9 ],
  [ 4.013, 'BILIa', 93.3 ]]

var array2 = [[ -2.9491, 'MSABb', 36.2 ],
  [ -2.9046, 'EMPIRb', 11.7 ],
  [ -2.8286, 'EDGE', 5.84 ]]
 var result = array1.map((row, index) => row.concat(array2[index]))

 console.log(result)
```